# How to pass IDialogParameters to the Regions of a Dialog

Tags: prism

I have a Prism Dialog displayed using **IDialogService.Showdialog();**

The Dialog window has some child Regions.

**The question is**: How to pass the **IDialogParameters** received by the dialog's VM through the **OnDialogOpened()** call to the VMs of the regions contained in the Dialog?

- Because the dialog's VM has no access to the different Regions of the dialog and thus no access to the VMs of these Regions, my idea was that when the dialog's VM receives the **OnDialogOpened(IDialogParameters params)** call, it can Publish the IDialogParameters it receives through the **EventAggregator** and the Region VMs could receive them by subscribing to the EventAggregator.
- The problem is that the Dialog's VM gets the **OnDialogOpened() call BEFORE** the Regions of the dialog are created - thus even if the dialog's VM  publishes the IDialogParameters received as parameters of the OnDialogOpened() call - the Regions of the dialog won't receive them because they have not yet been created.

Unfortunately this leads back to the original question stated above :(

Comment: Who fills the regions of the dialog? Or: why does the dialog have regions in the first place?

Comment: The Dialog has regions because I have multiple dialogs having to display a part/region that is common. Aren't regions meant exactly for such a scenario?!

Now indeed: "Who fills the regions?" that's the question.

My idea was that when the Regions are created they subscribe to the event bus and then, when the Dialog window receives the OnDialogOpened() call with the IDialogParameters, it passes the parameters to the regions by raising an event.


Unfortunately,  at this times, the regions are created AFTER the OnDialogOpened() call - so that they can't subscribe in time for the event.

Comment: The solution would be if Prism would call OndialogOpened() AFTER the regions are created OR if Prism would have another method BeforeDialogDisplayed() that gets called after the regions were created but before the dialog gets shown.

Comment: Region are _one_ option to do this, among others. Another one that's really straightforward is to use properties that expose view models shown by data templates in a content control. In your case, as you already have all information in the dialog view model already, I think it would be a good fit. One does not _have_ to use the view model locator, view model-first is at least as practicable most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure what you mean by "regions receiving an event", but you can store the information in the dialog's view model and then pass it on to the view models in the regions of the dialog when they are available.

Comment: The problem is that I didn't want to add code to the View itself.. after all MVVM is about not adding logic to the Views but adding it to the ViewModels.
It would be nice to have a notification when the dialog is all constructed on IDialogAware. 
Something like **IDialogAware.BeforeDisplayingDialog()**

Comment: I don't get it, the vm's `IDialogAware`, and it can provide any other vms you need in its properties. Perhaps you can rephrase the problem.

Comment: Okay, did try to rephrase it better in the original problem description.